# ValueError with attention Dimension1 in both shapes must be equal

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling, valueerror, attention-model

Hello together I have a problem
I am using python 3.6.5 and tensorflow 1.8.0. 
My input is 1000 max_textlength * 64 embedding * 4 steps and 3 protocolls = 64007
neuronumber = 10

a normal RNN works but I wanted to improve it with

`attentioncellwrapper(neurons, 2, state_is_tuple = True)`

I received the following message:

```
   Value Error: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 10 and
    20. Shapes are [?, 10) and [?, 20]. 
        From merging shape 1 with another shape for 'fully_connected/packed'(op: Pack) with input shapes [?,10], [?,10], [?,20]
```

why is this so? 
Has anyone also had this problem?

I was also experimenting with state_is_tuple = False,
no error message was given, but python suddenly crashed down :(

By the way, when I was changing the attention_length the e.g. from 2 to 3 or 4 this changed to

```
 Value Error: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 10 and
30. Shapes are [?, 10) and [?, 30]. 
 Value Error: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 10 and
40. Shapes are [?, 10) and [?, 40].
```

seems as if the attention length is multiplicated with the shape 
Thanks so much for help!